# How can I know a decompressing progress from TZDecompressionStream if I only know packed data size

Tags: delphi, stream, delphi-2010, zlib, compression

I'm using `TZDecompressionStream` to unpack compressed data. There is a property `OnProgress: TNotifyEvent` in `TZDecompressionStream` where I can check `Position` property of my DecompressionStream. It gives me position in unpacked data, but I don't now size of all unpacked data to estimate progress. I know only packed data size.

Is there is a way to get position in input (unpacked) data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TZDecompressionStream.Size` gives unpacked data size, but you must get this value before starting to read from stream (unpack). And if you try to get unpacked data size in `OnProgress` event handler you will get an `EZDecompressionError` exception with message 'buffer error'.

---

This error happens because `TStream.Size` getter retrieves a size by performing `Seek` **forward** to the end of stream and then `Seek` **backward** to the saved position. Latter operation is not supported due **unidirectional** nature of `TZDecompressionStream` see the 3rd paragraph of [class description](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.ZLib.TZDecompressionStream). Retrieval of size **before** starting an actual decompression operation is possible because [`Seek(0, soFromBeginning)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.ZLib.TZDecompressionStream.Seek) is allowed as a special case, which effectively resets decoder to initial state.